# how to fix problem with Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel-10

Hi for everyone I have a problem with Laravel , in My project show this message
Undefined type 'Route'.intelephense(P1009) in the folder storage/framework/views/c25e19d83b8e09fbed94d94670dc653e.php and The Route Class there is red underline ?

How can I fix this problem? thanks for all